# IE 9 throwing "Error: 'jQuery' is undefined" when launching from within an iFrame

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I have developed web application A that needs to be called from within web application B via an IFrame. I'm being forced to do it this way because application B is 3rd party and I don't have the source code to it.

Everything worked fine in IE 9 until I started using the IFrame. It gives me the error:

> 'jQuery' is undefined.

This doesn't happen in Firefox or Chrome. I have verified through IE's debugger that the jquery-ui-1.10.3 file is being pulled in.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Working with iFrames in IE is truly a dark art.

Comment: I'm guessing you're running into cross-domain issues. If you're calling the 3rd party app in from another domain, the jQuery you have will work on your page, but I believe it will be restricted from affecting the content inside the iframe.

Comment: But the same solution is working fine (so far) from within Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: In my case, reverting to jquery 1.x did the trick (instead of a 2.x version).

Answer (score 0):

You are likely using jQuery 1.10.1 which had a bug that affected IE and Opera. The bug caused jquery to error when being used within an iframe that is of a different origin than the parent page. Upgrading to the latest version of jquery (1.10.2 or 1.11+) will solve it.

Ref:http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980

jquery 2.0.2 was also affected by this bug, and was fixed in 2.0.3

Comment: I'm using jquery-2.0.3 and jquery-ui-1.10.3

Comment: And you've verified in the debugger that jquery 2.0.3 is loading? are you seeing any other errors in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that IE's "Document Mode" was set to IE7 Standards. I didn't realize there was a "Document Mode" in IE and I certainly don't remember setting it to IE7 from 9.

Anyway, now I have a related issue that the iFrame doesn't display with the correct height.